# Merging parquet files failed

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, schema, databricks

I am trying to merge schemas together. Unfortunately, two of them are different.. And I am getting an error org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed merging schema.Failed to merge incompatible data types string and double

I have tried a few ways to merge them together, but I can't find the way to fix this error. Do anyone know how to tackle this one?

Thank you

````py
df = spark.read.format("parquet").load(result.db_path)
old_columns = df.columns
for col in old_columns:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(col,col.lower())
df = df.withColumn("tenant", lit(payload.tenant))\
       .withColumn("filename", input_file_name())
write_format = 'delta'
save_path = f'dbfs:_________{endpoint.lower()}/'
db = f'--------'
name = f'{endpoint.lower()}_raas'
table_name = f'{db}.{name}'

if not spark._jsparkSession.catalog().tableExists(db,name):
    # Write the data to its target.
    df.write \
      .format(write_format) \
      .save(save_path)
    # Create the table.
    spark.sql("CREATE TABLE " + table_name + " USING DELTA LOCATION '" + save_path + "'")
else:
    df.write.format(write_format).mode("overwrite").save(save_path)```

I expect to merge schema with different values. Any ideas would be really helpful.
````

Comment: Post [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that SO contributors can copy-n-paste. When run it should produce a pair of dataframes, each with a couple rows, and then (unsuccessfully) attempt to merge those schemas. Also be sure to paste the **full** stacktrace as part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to load everything through one import, as `.format().load()`, then you can not proceed further if your files are not schema-compatible with each other.

What you can do in this case, is to *group* files that you know that have compatible schema, so you can cast them (for example, `String` to `Double`) then finally, union that with the rest of the files (the second group).

For example, let's say this is your case:

```
/path/file1   -> has column COL of type Int
/path/file2   -> has column COL of type String
/path/file3   -> has column COL of type Int
```

You can read files `file1` and `file3` together, union `file2` with a cast of `String` to `Int`.